# capistrano compile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have setup my deploy.rb and after much much suffering, I got it to deploy properly 3 times. I'm not sure what changed... as ive been dealing with problems the last 8 hours, but now there is an error that wasnt there before.

here is where it fails

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/username/u/apps/appname/releases/20120723030325 && #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007fef8a0826f0> RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on example.com
```

The only thing I can think of that is different that I added is this

```
namespace :rake do  
  task :seed, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /usr/bin/env rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production"
  end 
end
```

One other thing that MAY be related but i dont see how... in my production.log it says modernizr isnt precompiled. That's because its not actually inside application.js, the reason for this is because it needs to go at the top of the html document, not with all the rest at the bottom, so i just used a standard javascript_include tag, but i didnt put it the include tree. Although, it deployed 3 times fine, so I cant imagine thats the problem. Thats just the next one that i need to figure out :/

Other important note. I read somewhere i need to use `gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'`, so im using that as well for `group :production`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my `task :rake`... This was overriding capistranos :rake namespace, and it wasnt allowing me to precompile. I have sinced removed task :rake and its contents to a different namespace and now it works